# Is it appropriate to put master's and bachelor's theses into ORCID web page as dissertations?

Tags: thesis, digital-researcher-id

I recently registered to ORCID and put information of all my journal articles there. I started to think whether it's appropriate to put my master's and bachelor's theses there as well. ORCID doesn't have a category named "thesis", but there is a category named "dissertation".

Is it appropriate to put my master's and bachelor's theses to my ORCID web page using the category named "dissertation"? I have understood that the term "dissertation" usually refers to doctoral theses.

I think the bachelor's thesis might have some value there, as my university doesn't allow people to download bachelor's theses from the university web page, and people may not be aware of an alternative link to the file. Apparently they in the university think that all bachelor's theses are low-quality, but in my opinion my bachelor's and master's theses are very high-quality and have lots of merit. So I certainly am not planning to hide them!

Related question: [What is the difference between a thesis and a dissertation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31615/what-is-the-difference-between-a-thesis-and-a-dissertation)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is certainly appropriate and acceptable - but probably good to make clear the level of the document to avoid confusion. (I have my MSc thesis linked from my ORCID.)

The [Wikipedia article on "thesis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesis) gives a good overview of the difference in terminology - in short, "thesis" or "dissertation" can mean either an undergraduate work or a doctoral work, depending on the context and the location, and there is no single cast-iron rule. I wouldn't read too much into ORCID's choice of terms...